# How to ignore the width of images on the right side on small screen so that no scrollbar at the bottom shows up?

Tags: html, image, css

My designer just gave me  website which I need to use different images with z-index on them on both side of website. The image that I used on the left side is fine but the one on the right side shows a scroll bar on the bottom when opened on smaller screen resolution (below 1920 width).

So How can I get it right?

Take a look http://whitepixelstesting.com/sunexim/

Comment: You are supposed to first try, then ask. Please consider reading up on `response web design` and/or other general techniques to adapt your layout to screen size.

Comment: it's probably going to have to do with the overflow-x property but if you don't first attempt we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks @Domi and Joseph Dailey, I know I am not good like you guys, because I am just a beginner but I hope next time I'll give you better problems to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used background image, it would have been simpler.
But it this case, I would recommend you to use a CSS Media Query.

By adding **overflow: hidden** to your **#main_wrapper**, you solve the problem for screens between 1920px and 990px. If you keep the hidden overflow, you will hide your content for those below this screen width. That's why you should add this at the end of your Style Sheet:

```
@media all and (max-width: 991px) {
#main_wrapper {overflow: visible;}
.right_bg {display: none;}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't recommend using the picture for a background rather than this kludge.

Comment: That's why I talked about the background image on the very first line! Maybe we could have made it work with a background image, but that would have required to change the designer's layout. In this case, we have an overlaping image in the design. So I don't think the background image will do the trick if we want to keep the exact same layout.